# Is there a way to consolidate similar (but not the same) rows in a text file?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a text file on a linux box that has two columns.
1. An IP address
2. A code for a location

Some IP addresses are listed more than once because more than one code is associated with it.

Example:

```
140.90.218.62 vaac
140.90.220.11 aawu
140.90.220.11 afc
140.90.220.11 arh
140.90.220.40 afc
```

I would like to consolidate such IP addresses to only be listed once, just with several location codes

Like this

```
140.90.218.62 vaac
140.90.220.11 aawu:afc:arh
140.90.220.40 afc
```

I could always code a for loop to read in the file, consolidate the values into an array, and write the cleaned up version back out.

Before I do that I was wonder if a combination of *nix utilities might do the job, do it with less code, etc.

Comment: I'm the OP.  I was very happy with each answer I got.  All of them were very helpful and the one I accepted as THE answer was exactly what I was looking for. No problems here.  Thanks guys.

Comment: @Steve We were not talking about you; I'm sure you are very satisfied with the answers. But there's someone downvoting answers even though they address and solve the exact problem. That's a little discouraging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk

```
awk '{a[$1]=($1 in a?a[$1]":"$2:$2)}END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file
```

Output:

```
140.90.220.11 aawu:afc:arh
140.90.220.40 afc
140.90.218.62 vaac
```

Explanation:

- `a[$1]=($1 in a?a[$1]":"$2:$2)` - creates an indexed array with the IP address as key. Each `$2` with the same IP is concatenated to the current value separated by a colon if ther's already an value.
- `for (i in a) print i,a[i]` - when stdin closes, print all entries in `a`, the index (IP) first and all the values.

Comment: It works.  I did not know you could have two awk code blocks in one awk call.  I don't understand all of the code you wrote.  Would up update your answer with comments explaining step by step what your awk code is doing?

Comment: @Steve Sure, see edit.

Comment: You can avoid the trailing colon "problem" with `{a[$1] = $1 in a ? a[$1]":"$2 : $2}` -- then in the end block you can just use `print i, a[i]`

Comment: @glennjackman Good idea! I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

bash version 4, with associative arrays.

```
declare -A data
while read -r ip value; do
    data[$ip]+=":$value"
done < file

for key in "${!data[@]}"; do 
    printf "%s %s\n" "$key" "${data[$key]#:}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With perl:

```
perl -lanE 'push @{$ips{$F[0]}}, $F[1]; END { $" = ":"; say "$_ @{$ips{$_}}" for sort keys %ips }' yourfile.txt
```

outputs

```
140.90.218.62 vaac
140.90.220.11 aawu:afc:arh
140.90.220.40 afc
```